# How to find first duplicate item in a vector - C++?

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector with different values and some of them *may* appear twice. (Only twice.)
How can I find the FIRST duplicate item?

Like: [a][b][b][a]
Then I'd need 'b'.

(Sorry for the newbie question.)

Comment: if you know the values of the elements, lets say its the alphabet, you can have a vector<int> vec(26); and for every value you do vec[c-'a']++; and if its not zero then the value has appeared twice. Its faster then using a std::set. But then you have be sure what the values are.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're looking for adjacent duplicates, you can simply use [`std::adjacent_find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/adjacent_find/).

<s>If the duplicates aren't necessarily adjacent, then you could first [`std::sort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) the vector, and then use `std::adjacent_find` on the result.</s> *(See @aix's comment below)*

Alternatively, you could push each element into a [`std::set`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/), and look for collisions as you're doing it.

Comment: (+1) The sort method wouldn't necessarily locate the *first* duplicated as required by the question.

Answer (score 3):

There are many answers to this question. To find the **best** one, it's necessary to know the context of your usage scenario. For instance, is it **ok** that there are duplicates in the first place? What are you going to do with the result of the duplicate search? Can we use a parallel structure to the vector at all times? And more...

So, one way, of many, is to iterate the items and `insert` them to a `std::set<>`. Look at the `second` parameter of the returned `std::pair<>` to get whether the value existed in the set or not, then you'll get the first duplicate and can bail out of the `set`-adding.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use extra storage, there are roughly two solutions. The first is brute-force: For every element i, check if it equals the elements 0..i-1. This is `O(N*N)` (obvious worst case: last two elements are the first duplicates).

The second solution is to make the search faster, by keeping the range 0..i. sorted. You'll find the duplicates trivially during the sorting. A bubble sort is efficient because the range 0..i-1 was already sorted in the previous iteration. Still `O(N*N)` worst case, but `O(N)` if the range happened to be sorted before.